# Does it follow that any element of $J(A)$ is necessarily nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules, algebras

Let $A[x]$ be the algebra of polynomials with coefficients in a $k$-algebra $A$. Assume that, for any simple $A[x]$-module $M$, one has $\text{End}_{A[x]}M = k$. Does it follow that any element of $J(A)$ is necessarily nilpotent?

Comment: No, counterexample: $k= \Bbb{C}$, $A=\Bbb{C}[T]_{(T)}$. $A$ is a DVR, and its Jacobson radical is not zero. However, the only simple $A[x]$-modules are isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ (hence their endomorphism ring is $\Bbb{C}$).

Comment: @Crostul But in your example, the field $\mathbb{C}(T)$ of rational functions is a simple $A[x]$-module (with $x$ acting as multiplication by $T^{-1}$).

Comment: @JeremyRickard You are right! This was my only doubt (so I didn't post an answer, but a comment). By the way, I am suspecting that the claim is false. Maybe a good counterexample would be a local $k$-algebra of dimension $\neq 0$ (so that Jacobson radical and nilradical are distinct), with $k$ algebraically closed.

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222104/does-it-follow-that-any-element-of-ja-is-nilpotent

Comment: I think it's true if $A$ is commutative. But maybe the OP already knows that?